# GORM Mapping View

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an Domain Class called `Contact` with multiple hasMany Relationships and another Domain Class `Employee` which is part of `Concat`.

`Contact` has an table `contact` and Employee should be mapped on a View which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contact where employee=1
```

`Employee` should have the same columns and Relationship than `Contact`, how do I write the Domain Classes?
Can I use inheritance?

**EDIT**

Now I have used inheritance like this:

```
class Employee extends Contact { }
class Contact{
    static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy(false)
    }
}
```

That works so far, but now I want to add some Relationships to `Employee`, like this:

```
 class Employee extends Contact {      
     static belongsTo = [CostCenter ]
     static hasMany = [costCenter: CostCenter]
     static mapping = { 
     costCenter joinTable: 'employee_cost_center', column: 'employee_id'
     }
 }
 class CostCenter {
   static hasMany = [employees:Employee]
    static mapping = { 
     employeesjoinTable: 'employee_cost_center', column: 'cost_center_id'
     }
 }
```

now I have the problem that the table 'employee_cost_center' makes an referen to `Contact` which is good, but also added 'employee_id':

```
contact_id
employee_id
cost_center_id
```

So i could add the relationships to Contact but then I have in `CostCenter` `Contact` and not `Employee`.

How can I add Relationships to `Employee`?

Comment: Why must `Employee` subclass `Contact`? Do you need the polymorphism provided by inheritance?

Comment: I'm looking fo a good solution for the whole Problem, the solution doesn't need to use inheritance. If you have another idea let me here it.

Comment: As long as the `Contact` *hasMany*s do not have a *belongsTo* back to `Contact` you can use a Groovy trait. The trait would contain the properties and associations in `Contact` and `Employee` would get them by implementing the trait. This means there wouldn't be a contact entity/domain class. Other domain classes would be able to implement the trait too.

Comment: Never mind, that won't work because adding the hasMany to cost center will override the hasManys in the trait. Besides, if Employee is backed by a view which selects from a contact table, then an employee is a contact, which implies inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on track using inheritance. Since `Employee` is backed by a database view which selects a **subset** of `Contact`s, an `Employee` *is a* `Contact`. So you've got a good candidate for inheritance.

## Table-per-subclass inheritance

You described the `employee` view as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM contact where employee=1
```

When using table-per-subclass inheritance the table generated for subclasses contain the following columns:

1. ID (primary key)
2. Columns for properties added to the subclass (are not in the superclass), excluding properties for associations.

Since `Employee` does not, and cannot add, additional properties, the view should only return the primary key.

```
SELECT id FROM contact where employee=1
```

I have an [article](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-inheritance/) that compares *table-per-hierarchy* to *table-per-subclass* inheritance and demonstrates what it looks like at the database level.

## Join tables

In your domain class examples you described a join table to create the *many-to-many* relationship between `Employee` and `CostCenter`. Join tables should have two, and only two, columns:

1. The foreign key (the *me* domain class)
2. The foreign key of the *other* domain class.

So your `employee_cost_center` table should have the columns `employee_id` and `cost_center_id`. If you must specify the join table explicitly, use `key` instead of `column`.

```
costCenter joinTable: 'employee_cost_center', key: 'employee_id'
employees joinTable: 'employee_cost_center', key: 'cost_center_id'
```

## belongsTo

You have `Employee` *belong to* `CostCenter` as so:

```
static belongsTo = [CostCenter ]
```

Maybe that's a typo, but if you're not defining a back-reference then the *belongsTo* should be defined as simply the class, like this:

```
static belongsTo = CostCenter
```

I've never used *belongsTo* this way so I don't know what it looks like in the database. But note that if you have a back-reference, defined like this:

```
static belongsTo = [costCenter: CostCenter]
```

Then, your `employee` view must return a `cost_center` column.

Comment: Why should I select only the `id` in the database View? I would need to make always a join to get informations from `contact` and thats not what i wanted, therefor I've made the view, that I can access to the informations from `Contact`without making a where clause or something else to select the `Employee`'s

Comment: Because with table per subclass inheritance that's how gorm would create the employee table. You can see this in action in my article. Gorm will join contact and employee every time you query the employee domain class.